# ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (224,224) (180,180)

Tags: python, numpy

I am writing a program to find the cosine similarity between two vectors. For small text files it works fine but for large datas it gives error. I have gone through many examples of broadcasting but couldn't get the actual problem. (Getting an error at line p=x*y)

```
x = numpy.dot(u, u.T)
y = numpy.dot(v, v.T)
p = x * y
value = numpy.dot(u, v.T) / p

p=(x*y)
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (224,224) (180,180)
```

Comment: It seems that the shape of `x` is `(224, 224)` whereas the shape of `y` is `(180, 180)` can you confirm and post that here?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to compute the norms of `x` and `y`. Use `numpy.linalg.norm` for that.

Comment: What are the shapes of `u` and `v`, i.e. `print u.shape, v.shape`. Would need you to explain better where those come from, but it may all be as easy as swapping `u` and `u.T` in the calculation of `x` (and `v` and `v.T` for `y`).

Answer (score 2):

Your variable **x** and variable **y** have different "dimensions". You should try to make sure they have similar "dimensions", i.e 224,224 and 224,224 or 180,180 and 180,180.

I.e with numpy "multiplication" it will not be possible to multiple two **numpy arrays** with different "dimensions".

For example

```
x = np.linspace(1,10,num=224)
y = np.linspace(1,10,num=180)
p = x*y

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    p = x*y
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (224,) (180,)
```

But

```
 x = np.linspace(1,10,num=224)
 y = np.linspace(1,10,num=224)
 p = x*y
```

will work

Comment: yes, the shapes are different. Shape of x is (224,224) and shape of y is(180,180). But here I am reading two documents, converting them to vector form and then trying to find cosine similarity. So from this whether it means that I can compute cosine similarity only for documents of same length.@Midnighter  @larsmans

Answer (score 2):

If `x` and `y` do not have the same shape, then you will get this type of error. 
they all must be the same shape. Please read [this](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) `numpy` broadcast rule